# customizing setup using NSIS Script Editor

Tags: nsis

I developed customize setup wizard using NSIS Editor. Setup allows an user to Install an application in only
available Drive Letter In Client Machine, shown in combobox  . But problem is that removable Drive like PENDRIVE also detects in Setup Wizard if it is connected ,

Is that Possible to not detecting Removable Drive In Setup Wizard

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin that maybe can help you http://nsis.sourceforge.net/GetDrives